# persist environment variable value which changed from ant sshexec task

Tags: linux, ant

I have created an environment variable named "COUNTER" in "etc/environment" and assigned a value 0 to it. I want to **increment and persist** its value by using ant script's SSHEXEC task. I wrote the following code to increment its value:

```
 <target name="incrementCounter">
    <sshexec 
        host="${remote.host.ip}" 
        username="${remote.user.id}" 
        password="${remote.user.ssh.password}" 
        command="((++COUNTER))"
        trust="true"
        useSystemIn="true"
    />
 </target>
```

After command is executed successfully I logged in into linux machine through Secure Shell Client and printed its value, it showed me "0". Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable changes are local to the process which makes them, so this could not possibly work.

You can hack up an ever-increasing counter just by maintaining appropriate file and sourcing it., much like /etc/environment is sourced.

However, the real question is what you are really trying to achieve.